# MS Graph copy Sharepoint folder with contents to new folder

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, copy

I'm trying to accomplish the following, copy one SharePoint folder with contents (files, subfolders, etc) to a new folder using Microsoft.Graph library and C#.

Is there a way to do this in one step? Been doing some reading and cannot find any other solution than recursivly iterate and copy the objects (files, folders) one by one.

Thomas